# organizing category table in mysql with query

Tags: mysql

I got a classic category table in mysql with three fields : id, name, parentid.

I'd like to get for each parent category query which returns first the  main category  (parentid =0) and then all the sub-categories which have as parentid the parent category id and then display everything in a table.

The desired output is the following:

```
<tr> <td> Parent Category 1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Child category 1 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Child category 1 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Parent Category 2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Child category 2 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Child category 2 </td> </tr>
```

What kind of query should I use?

Comment: MySQL has basically no support for hierarchical or recursive queries.  Three methods comes to mind for solving this:  (1) Change your data structure to include the complete path for each category; (2) Use a stored procedure; (3) Switch to another database that supports ANSI standard recursive CTEs.

Comment: show your desired sample output

Comment: ...or switch to nested sets, or handle the logic in application code

Comment: the desired output is the following :


    `<tr> <td> Parent Category  1</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Child category 1 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Child category 1 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Parent Category  2</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Child category 2 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Child category 2 </td> </tr>`